# Can I use ElasticSearch mapping transform to duplicate a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I read here about mapping transform: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html

> The result of the transform is indexed but the original source is
>   stored in the _source field.

So I thought I can use it to "copy" a field. I try:

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "opportunity":{
         "transform":{
            "script":"ctx._source['skill_suggest']=ctx._source['skill']"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I perform the query on the "skill_suggest" field but return no result (the same query on "skill" work fine).

So what I'm doing wrong?
Can I some how "copy" some fields on the fly? I want to perform full-text seach on "skill" but also the [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) but I cannot modify the data schema sent from client.

Comment: Why don't you use "multi-fields"? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html

Comment: @AndreiStefan I try this mapping with "multi-fields" http://pastebin.com/YM46WcXc . Then I try to get the suggest with http://pastebin.com/VdwYVhmB and getting these failures http://pastebin.com/1c8eJMjs . Maybe I should post a new question :D

Comment: Try with `"completion" : {
            "field" : "Skills.Name.NameSuggest"
        }`

Comment: @AndreiStefan you save my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect match for `multi-fields`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html